# C program can't figure out how to properly free mallocs

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

In the main function of my program I make a few malloc calls and what I think are the right free calls at the end. My address sanitizer is telling me that data is still leaking in line 206, which is:

```
names[size - 1] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
```

The problem is that if I include a free statement for names[size - 1], there is apparently data still leaking from it. I have no idea why. Here is the main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
if (argc - 1 != 1) {
    printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
    return 0;
}

//get file, return if invalid path
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (!file) {
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    return 0;
}

//make temp of circuit with struct directive
int scount = 0;
struct directive* temp = NULL;
int size = 2;
int icount = 0;
int ocount = 0;
int tcount = 0;
char dir[17];
char **names;
int *values;

//get INPUT info
fscanf(file, " %s", dir);
fscanf(file, "%d", &icount);

size += icount;
names = malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
names[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));     //MALLOC
strcpy(names[0], "0");
names[1] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));     //MALLOC
strcpy(names[1], "1");

int i;
for (i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
    names[i + 2] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
    fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", names[i + 2]);
}

//get OUTPUT info
fscanf(file, " %s", dir);
fscanf(file, "%d", &ocount);
size += ocount;
names = realloc(names, size * sizeof(char *));
for (i = 0; i < ocount; i++) {
    names[i + icount + 2] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
    fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", names[i + icount + 2]);
}

//get temp
struct directive step;
while (!feof(file)) {
    int numInputs = 2, numOutputs = 1;
    
    int sc = fscanf(file, " %s", dir); 
    if (sc != 1) {
        break;
    }
    scount++;
    step.n = 0;
    step.s = 0;
    strcpy(step.gate, dir);

    if (strcmp(dir, "NOT") == 0) {
        numInputs = 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(dir, "PASS") == 0) {
        numInputs = 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(dir, "DECODER") == 0) {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &numInputs);
        step.n = numInputs;
        numOutputs = pow(2, numInputs);
    }
    if (strcmp(dir, "MULTIPLEXER") == 0) {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &numInputs);
        step.s = numInputs;
        numInputs = pow(2, numInputs);
    }

    step.inputs = malloc(numInputs * sizeof(int));
    step.outputs = malloc(numOutputs * sizeof(int));
    step.selectors = malloc(step.s * sizeof(int));

    char v[17];
    for (i = 0; i < numInputs; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", v);
        step.inputs[i] = indexOf(size, names, v);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < step.s; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", v);
        step.selectors[i] = indexOf(size, names, v);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numOutputs; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", v);
        int idx = indexOf(size, names, v);
        if (idx == -1) {
            size++;
            tcount++;
            char **tmp = realloc(names, size * sizeof *tmp);
            if (!tmp) abort(); // handle alloc failure
            names = tmp;
            names[size - 1] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(names[size - 1], v);
            step.outputs[i] = size - 1;
        }
        else {
            step.outputs[i] = idx;
        }
    }
    
    //add step to list of temp
    if (!temp) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct directive));
    } else {
        temp = realloc(temp, scount * sizeof(struct directive));
    }
    temp[scount - 1] = step;

    
}

// initialize values array
values = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
resetValues(size, values);

while(1 < 2) {
    //print inputs
    for (i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
        printf("%d ", values[i + 2]);
    }
    printf("|");

    //run through temp, calculate outputs
    for (i = 0; i < scount; i++) {
        struct directive step = temp[i];
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "NOT") == 0) {
            NOT(values, step.inputs[0], step.outputs[0]);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "AND") == 0) {
            AND(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "OR") == 0) {
            OR(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "NAND") == 0) {
            NAND(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "NOR") == 0) {
            NOR(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "XOR") == 0) {
            XOR(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "PASS") == 0) {
            PASS(values, step.inputs[0], step.outputs[0]);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "DECODER") == 0) {
            DECODER(values, step.n, step.inputs, step.outputs);
        }
        if (strcmp(step.gate, "MULTIPLEXER") == 0) {
            MUX(values, step.s, step.inputs, step.selectors, step.outputs[0]);
        }
        
    }

    //print outputs
    for (i = 0; i < ocount; i++) {
        printf(" %d", values[icount + i + 2]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    if (!incrementInputs(values, icount)) {
        break;
    }
    
}




    for (i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
    free(names[i + 2]);
    }

for (i = 0; i < ocount; i++) {
    free(names[i + icount + 2]);
  
}

for (int i = 0; i < scount; i++) {
  free(temp[i].inputs);
  free(temp[i].outputs);
  free(temp[i].selectors);
}


free(names[0]);
free(names[1]);
//free(names[size-1]);

free(values);
free(temp);
free(names);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Note that the incorrect use of `feof()` can cause a program to act as if there is more data than there actually is. Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Unsure if it will cause issues here - you are mixing its use with `fscanf` but you can control a loop with *just* `fscanf`. However you don't always check that `fscanf` succeeds.

Comment: Going in to the big loop `size = icount + ocount + 2`. Then you increase size at `size++;` and allocate more with `names[size - 1] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));` but I don't think you take that into account when freeing.

Comment: I think that the way you are managing the `names[]` array is confusing the compiler (and you). Have you considered abstracting it from the code somewhat? Also, the way you are using `realloc()` is asking for pain.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp What be the loop that I should put free(names[size - 1]) in then?

Comment: I would get rid of the two loops and the end and just do `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) free(names[i])'` since `size` seems to be the total size of that array. This should free all including the ones at `0` and `1`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You my sir are an absolute hero